# Splitting string with comma into seperate columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to split columns for coordinates into their respective `lat` and `lng` columns

In the `coordinates` columns i have these

```
-74.93360137939453, 40.07080078125
-101.473911, 38.704022
-151.695999146, 59.94919968
```

but when i run the code below,

```
  UPDATE `data`
      SET `lat`  = TRIM(SUBSTR(`coordinates`,INSTR(`coordinates`,',')-1))
        , `lng` = TRIM(SUBSTR(`coordinates`,INSTR(`coordinates`,',')+1));
```

it adds it to the columns like this

```
3, 40.07080078125 | 40.07080078125
1, 38.704022      | 38.704022
6, 59.94919968    | 59.94919968
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substring_index

```
 select  trim(Substring_index('74.93360137939453, 40.07080078125',',',1)),
   trim(substring_index(substring_index('74.93360137939453, 40.07080078125',',',-1),',',1)) 

select  trim(Substring_index(your_col,',',1)),
   trim(substring_index(substring_index(your_col,',',-1),',',1)) 
FROM your_table


UPDATE `data`
  SET `lat` = trim(Substring_index(coordinates,',',1)),
      `lng` =  trim(substring_index(substring_index(coordinates,',',-1),',',1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here, but if you want to continue with your current approach, then try this:

```
UPDATE data
SET
    lat = SUBSTRING(coordinates, 1, INSTR(coordinates, ',') - 1),
    lng = SUBSTRING(coordinates, INSTR(coordinates, ',') + 2);
```

Your update assignment for the longitude was incorrect.  The logic you want is to *begin* taking the substring two positions after the comma, until the end of the `coordinates` string.

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You just forgot to set the starting index for the first substring.

```
UPDATE `data`
    SET `lat` = TRIM(SUBSTR(`coordinates`,1,INSTR(`coordinates`,',')-1))
      , `lng` = TRIM(SUBSTR(`coordinates`,INSTR(`coordinates`,',')+1));
```